# PRedis/Laravel failed to resolve host on boot - [tcp://:6379]

Tags: laravel, docker, redis, rancher, predis

I'm having a issue with my Laravel/Redis docker stack on Rancher. When ever it boots Predis has this error

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve [tcp://:6379]
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
        services:
      app:
        image: REDACTED/services-intranet:${APP_VERSION}
        environment:
          - DB_MIGRATE=true
          - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
          - DB_HOST=${STAGING_DB_HOST}
          - DB_PORT=${STAGING_DB_PORT}
          - DB_DATABASE=${STAGING_DB_DATABASE}
          - DB_USERNAME=${STAGING_DB_USERNAME}
          - DB_PASSWORD=${STAGING_DB_PASSWORD}
          - REDIS_HOST=redis
          - REDIS_PORT=6379
          - JWT_TOKEN=${JWT_TOKEN}
          - APP_KEY=${STAGING_APP_KEY}
          - APP_URL=${INTRANET_URL}
          - AUTH_URL=${AUTH_URL}
          - AUDIT_URL=${AUDIT_URL}
          - BILLING_URL=${BILLING_URL}
          - BUSINESSES_URL=${BUSINESSES_URL}
          - GROUPS_URL=${GROUPS_URL}
          - MESSAGING_URL=${MESSAGING_URL}
          - PERMISSIONS_URL=${PERMISSIONS_URL}
          - UI_URL=${UI_URL}
          - USERS_URL=${USERS_URL}
        labels:
            io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: type=node
            io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: services=true
        depends_on:
          - redis
        command: sh -c '/run/wait-for.sh redis:6379 --timeout=30 --strict -- /run/start.sh'
        links:
          - redis:redis
      redis:
        image: REDACTED/services-redis:staging-latest
        command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
        volumes:
          - intranet-redis:/data
        labels:
          io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: type=database
          io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: redis=true
        restart: always
    volumes:
      intranet-redis:
        driver: local
```

The wait-for.sh script works fine and it finds redis no problem. But it appears that its failing during the supervisord.conf for the app container

```
    [supervisord]
    logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log     ; supervisord log file
    logfile_maxbytes=50MB                           ; maximum size of logfile before rotation
    logfile_backups=10                              ; number of backed up logfiles
    loglevel=error                                  ; info, debug, warn, trace
    pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid                ; pidfile location
    nodaemon=true                                   ; run supervisord NOT as a daemon
    minfds=1024                                     ; number of startup file descriptors
    minprocs=200                                    ; number of process descriptors
    user=root                                       ; default user
    childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor/                ; where child log files will live

    [program:php-fpm]
    command=php-fpm7 -F
    stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
    stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
    stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
    stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
    autorestart=false
    startretries=0

    [program:nginx]
    command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
    stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
    stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
    stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
    autorestart=false
    startretries=0

    [program:laravel-worker]
    process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
    command=php /web/html/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    user=root
    numprocs=2
    redirect_stderr=true
    stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
    stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
    stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
    stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

If I SSH into the container I can use redis-cli to ping the redis server and all DNS resolving is completed correctly, its just that initial boot.

Comment: REDIS_HOST=redis

Comment: sorry it was a edited docker-compose I was using for testing. REDIS_HOST was set to redis and linked via docker-compose links

Comment: A quick pointer, you don't need to use links in rancher. You can resolve services within the same stack directly using their names.